# What is more important, normalization or ease of coding?

Tags: database, normalization

I have an excel spreadsheet i am going to be turning into a DB to mine data and build an interactive app.  There are about 20 columns and 80,000 records.  Practically all records have about half of their column data as null, but which column has data is random for each record.

The options would be to:

1. Create a more normalized DB with a table for each column and use 20 joins to view all data.  I would think the benefits would be a DB with really no NULL values so the size would be smaller.  One of the major cons would be more code to update each table from the application side.
2. Create a flat file with one table that has all columns.  I figure this will be easier for the application side to do updates, but will result in a table that has a butt load of empty dataspace.

Comment: What's the connection between "many null fields" and normalization? If you have 80.000 different database programmers (identified by their social security number) and 20 columns for the days 1/1/2011 ... 1/20/2011 to state whether they normalized their Database on this day, you have a perfect - if sparse - table. To optimize storage, you would need one (not twenty) table (ssn,date).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't get why you think updating a normalized db is *harder* than a flat table. It's very much the other way around.

Think about inserting a relation between a customer and a product (basically an order). You'd have to:

1. select the row that describes the rest of the data, but has nulls or something in the product columns
2. you have to update the product columns
3. you have to insert a HUGE row to the db

What about the first time? What do you do with the initial nulls? Do you modify your selects to ignore them? What if you *want* the nulls?

What if you delete the last product? Do you change it into an update and set nulls for just a few columns?

---

Joins aside, working with a normalized table is *trivial* by design. You *pay* for its triviality with performance, that's the actual trade-off.

Comment: I don't think it would be harder, I just think it would take more coding with doing an update for each column separately instead of one line to update a larger row.  The question then is would more coding make the application slower, or would a larger database make the application slower.

Comment: @sfreelander, you're still asking the wrong question. There is almost no way a non-normalized database is better than a normalized one *for the entire application*. What big data clusters like Google do however is they denormalize their databases for querying every couple of hours, but keep their master database normalized for their crawler inserts. This way they get the best of both worlds.

Comment: @sfreelander: The canonical model for the application is a good way to get into unnecessary complexity. See CQRS, DDD and other ideas on top of OO. A single model is fine for Acitive Record type apps with forms-over-data type of CRUD manipulation. Behaviour is where a non-trivial system centers around. To force it to one model is short-sighted. But in this case, the system may be fine with one model, especially if it's all CRUD. So don't be afraid to denormalize, just make sure you're not doing it just out of laziness.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to be using a relational database, you should normalize your tables, if nothing else in order to ease data maintenance and ensure you don't have duplicate data.

You can investigate the use of a [document database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database) for storage instead of a relational database, though it is [not the only option](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/05/which-database-right-for-me/).

Comment: +1: Ease of use is generally a matter of familiarity, which really should not be the deciding factor in how to approach things.

Answer (score 1):

Generally normalized databases will end up being easier to write code against as SQl code is deisgned with normalized tables in mind.

Comment: @adymitruk, your comment makes no sense and clearly shows your ignorance of database programming.

Answer (score 1):

Normalizing doesn't have to be done on all columns, so there's a middle ground between the two options you present.  A good rule of thumb is that if you have columns that have values being repeated heavily across records, those can be good candidates for normalizing into one or more separate tables.  Putting each column in its own table and joining across them is almost certainly overdoing it.

Answer (score -4):

Don't normalize too much. It's hard to maintain a canonical model as your application grows. Storage is cheap. Don't get fooled into coding head aches because of concerns that were valid 20 years ago. No need to go nosql unless you need it.

Comment: Normalization isn't just about storage space.  It's also about data integrity.  The more you duplicate data, the easier it is for the data to get out of sync -- and by the time that happens, it becomes a pain in the ass to try and figure out which is the valid data.

Comment: Not really. Duplication is necessary for storing multiple models. Cramming multiple concerns into one model.

Comment: Which sounds like a horrible idea anyway.